# DotLiquid, some beginner questions/observations

Tags: c#, .net, template-engine, liquid, dotliquid

I'm investigating using [dotliquid](http://dotliquidmarkup.org/) to replace a home grown piece of templating code and I'm wondering about the best way to achieve my goal.

The old code used to use sigils in the template and, together with a Dictionary, used regexes to search and replace. So you did something like this in the template file:

```
Specific error: {#ErrorId#}
Error description: {#Description#}
Additional information:{#AdditionalInformation#}
```

And in the C# code:

```
Dictionary<string, string> tokensAndValues = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {@"ErrorId", errorId},
    {@"Description", description},
    {@"AdditionalInformation", additionalInformation}
};
```

I came across dotnetliquid and it appears quite powerful (possibly overkill for my needs?). I've got it working but I want to ask if I'm going about this in the correct fashion?

It appears I'm forced to declare a class viz.

```
public class EmailTemplateInfo : Drop
{
    public string ErrorId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string AdditionalInformation { get; set; }
}
```

And then use that as follows:

```
Template.NamingConvention = new CSharpNamingConvention();
Template template = Template.Parse(templateText);

EmailTemplateInfo emailTemplateInfo = new EmailTemplateInfo
{
    AdditionalInformation = additionalInformation,
    Description = description,                    
    ErrorId = errorId
};

string htmlText = template.Render(Hash.FromAnonymousObject(new {emailTemplateInfo = emailTemplateInfo }));
```

A few questions:

1. Is this the correct way to do this? If it is then I'll propose doing an addition to the docs that demonstrates this functionality.
2. Secondly in the template that I use do I need to qualify the placeholders with the name of the variable like this?

   ```
   Specific error: {{emailTemplateInfo.ErrorId}}
   Error description: {{emailTemplateInfo.Description}}
   Additional information:{{emailTemplateInfo.AdditionalInformation}}
   ```
3. I can't see how the naming convention declaration [`Template.NamingConvention = new CSharpNamingConvention();`] ties in with the template variable declaration below it. Is there some sort of global caching going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, inheriting from `Drop` is one way to do it. The other mechanism that DotLiquid provides is `Template.RegisterSimpleType(...)` - see the [unit tests](https://github.com/dotliquid/dotliquid/blob/master/src/DotLiquid.Tests/TemplateTests.cs#L173) for examples.
2. Yes, you do need to qualify property names with the name of the variable, as in your example. The alternative would be to create a `Hash` containing top-level keys for `AdditionalInformation`, `Description`, `ErrorId`, and pass that to `template.Render(...)`. You can do that using `Hash.FromDictionary(...)`, as shown [here](https://github.com/dotliquid/dotliquid/blob/20e736602bf0e9fc369a60e40249e88ec2084808/src/DotLiquid.Tests/ConditionTests.cs#L208).
3. The naming convention doesn't have a connection to the variable declaration. The naming convention is only used when resolving property names. For example, if you used `RubyNamingConvention`, then you'd need to write `{{ emailTemplateInfo.additional_information }}` in your template.

Comment: @TimJones Why people focused so much on `Drop`s? I used `Template.RegisterSafeType(Type, string[])` with composite nested models that contain other models, dictionary   -works great. Only issue I have - how to use `{{ model.dict.key | filter }}` and apply specific culture, only not like `... filter:"xx-Xx"` Basically, is `Context` available in filters?