# replace text value with data dynamic based on column

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to replace the values of a text with the data retrieve(DataSet) from database based on column name, example:

SQL:

```
SELECT Fullname, Age FROM User
```

I have a text:

```
Hello my name is <<Fullname>> and my age is <<Age>>
```

Result:

```
Hello my name is Alvin and my age is 18
```

SQL:

```
SELECT Lastname, Feeling FROM User
```

I have a text:

```
Hello my name is <<Lastname>> and I am <<Feeling>>
```

Result:

```
Hello my name is Lee and I am Happy
```

Comment: Query the data and then use replace function on string

Comment: The column name is different and dynamic

Comment: please post the real code where you retrieve the data from database

Comment: As long as you don´t show your current code this question has nothing to do with C# or any other programming-related question. Where specifically are you stuck/do you have difficulties? Currently it´s really hard to understand what you´re actually asking. Allways answer the following questions in order to get help on StackOverflow: What is your input? What your desired output? What do you get instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One excellent open-source solution which I recently used is [dotliquid](http://dotliquidmarkup.org/)

Please refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42110717/dotliquid-some-beginner-questions-observations) where I detail what I did to get started, and also check out Tim's excellent answer

You can execute your query, construct a POCO and use that to populate your template. You can read the template text from anywhere - a file, a database column, a web service etc.

As a rough idea of how you'd go about it:

```
public class PersonTemplateInfo : Drop
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Feeling { get; set; }
}
```

And then use that as follows:

```
// Code to read templateText here

Template.NamingConvention = new CSharpNamingConvention();
Template template = Template.Parse(templateText);

// Code to read values

PersonTemplateInfo personTemplateInfo = new PersonTemplateInfo
{
    Name = name,
    Feeling = feeling
};

string parsedText = template.Render(Hash.FromAnonymousObject(new {personTemplateInfo = personTemplateInfo }));
```

Comment: This is merely a comment than an answer, isn´t it?

Comment: What if you can't define what to be replace. You just replace column name in the template with the column value.

Comment: Exactly, you're going have to start from a known point, so read in the template and make the changes to the sigils and then replace. Does that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, below code look like what u need. I just type directly here so, u just get the idea and correct it if u feel its useful.

```
   SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT Fullname, Age,Lastname, Feeling,OtherProperties FROM User", connString);
        da.Fill(ds, "User");
        dt = ds.Tables["User"];

        var resultText = "Hello, ";
        var textDic = new Dictionary<string,string>(){
           {"Fullname","And My name is {0}"},
           {"Age","And My age is {0}"},
           {"LastName","And my name is {0}"},
           {"Felling","And I am  {0}"}, 
           {"OtherProperties","And whatever  {0}"}, 
         };

         foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                ColumnName = column.ColumnName;
                ColumnData = row[column].ToString();
                if(textDic.ContainsKey(ColumnName))
                {
                    resultText+= string.Format(textDic[ColumnName],ColumnData)
                }
            }
        }

// your final result is this resultText
```

Comment: What if you can't define what to be replace. You just replace column name in the template with the column value.